# How to blur an image when scrolling with css/javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am learning to make websites, and I have been struggling with this problem the entire day. I'd like to gradually blur an image when scrolling, then make it go back to the state from before when going back up

Here's a snippet from my css and html for the part that I want to blur:

```css
.home-header {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url(write.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  margin: auto;
}

.blur {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
  -moz-filter: blur(10px);
  -o-filter: blur(10px);
  -ms-filter: blur(10px);
  filter: blur(10px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="home-header blur">
  <div class="banner-text">
    <p>Banner text</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function(e) {
      var s = $(window).scrollTop(),
        opacityVal = (s / 200);

      $('.blur').css('opacity', opacityVal);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Thank you!

Comment: ah I also changed it and now it shows something, however I want the image to gradually blur as I'm scrolling, then revert to its initial state once I go back up. Does that make sense?? Thanks anyways!

Comment: Sorry! I'll edit it immediately, the change should not be that big so I'll change as you said. How do I set the opacity to change as I scroll down?

Comment: I think you are confusing opacity with the css filter blur. You want to change that, not the opactity. So that it is not blurred when scrolled to the top but blurred more as you scroll down?

Comment: yes, alright then, thanks!

Comment: Please see my updated answer. It should give you what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue comes from the fact that you have `opacity` set to zero on `className` `blur`, so nothing shows in the view. Since you clarified that you want to update the `CSS` filter `blur` as you scroll down, I have set `opacity` to remain at 1.0 and modify the filter as you scroll. Please see the following snippet, I changed from division by 200 as that seemed like a lot to just division by 20 to demonstrate the affect you want. You can change this to whatever you deem necessary.

```css
.home-header {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url(write.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  margin: auto;
}

.blur {
  opacity: 1.0;
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
  -moz-filter: blur(0px);
  -o-filter: blur(0px);
  -ms-filter: blur(0px);
  filter: blur(0px);
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"
  integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="home-header blur">
  <div class="banner-text">
    <p>Banner text</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
  </div>
</div>
   <div>
   L
   <br/>
   L
   <br/>
   L
   <br/>
   L
   <br/>
   L
   <br/>
   L
   <br/>
   L
   <br/>
   L
   <br/>
   L
   <br/>
   L
   <br/>
   L
   <br/>
   L
   <br/>
   L
   <br/>
   </div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function(e) {
      let s = $(window).scrollTop(),
        filterVal = s === 0 ? 0 : Math.ceil((s / 20));

      $('.blur').css({
                       'filter'         : 'blur(' + filterVal + 'px)',
                       '-webkit-filter' : 'blur(' + filterVal + 'px)',
                       '-moz-filter'    : 'blur(' + filterVal + 'px)',
                       '-o-filter'      : 'blur(' + filterVal + 'px)',
                       '-ms-filter'     : 'blur(' + filterVal + 'px)'
                    });
    });
  });
</script>
```